# Are the following statements True for all functions f and for all subsets A, B and C of the domain of f?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I came across this question in my assignment:

Are the following true for all functions f and for all subsets A, B and C of the domain f?

(i) $(\{f(x): x\in A\} \cup \{f(x):x\in B \}) \cap \{f(x):x\in C\}$ is a subset of $(\{f(x):x \in A\}\cap \{f(x):x\in B \}) \cup \{f(x):x\in C\}$

(ii) $(\{f(x):x \in A \} \cap \{f(x):x \in B\}) \cup \{f(x):x \in C\}$ is a subset of $(\{f(x):x \in A\} \cup \{f(x):x \in B\}) \cap \{f(x):x \in C\}$

The way I reasoned this was I assume some random elements for A,B,C and then I calculated the results. And the answer I came up with: True for (i) and False for (ii).

Can anyone tell me if the answer is correct, or I am not supposed to do it this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "assume some random elements", but one can show (i) is True by arguing an *arbitrary* element $x\in (\{f(x): x\in A\} \cup \{f(x):x\in B \}) \cap \{f(x):x\in C\}$ would necessarily belong to $(\{f(x):x \in A\}\cap \{f(x):x\in B \}) \cup \{f(x):x\in C\}$.  Do you see why?

Comment: Use definition of image: $f(X)=\{y\colon \exists x\in X \land y=f(x)  \}$.
Then your properties can be write as:
$$f(A) \cup f(B)\cap f(C) \subset f(A) \cap f(B)\cup f(C) \quad (i)$$
$$f(A) \cap f(B)\cup f(C) \subset f(A) \cup f(B)\cap f(C) \quad (ii)$$

Comment: @hardmath by assuming some random elements I meant by doing something like this
A = {1,2,3}, B={4,5,6}, C = {7,8,9}

How did you reason with your method for (i)?

Comment: @zkutch Oh I see, thank you for this. I did it using this method by accident and I didn't know if I was doing it right. Thank you again for the confirmation.

Comment: Brackets are essential in set operations, because, for example, $(A\cup B)\cap C \ne A \cup (B \cap C)$. Often intersection have priority, but what mean you in your case?

Comment: I just made up a couple of elements for A,B,C. For example: A = {1,2,3}, B = {4,5,6}, C = {7,8,9}. Then I find out the results for $(A \cup B ) \cap C$ and see if the result is a subset of $(A \cap B) \cup C$

Comment: Such way is useful for counterexamples, but not for direct prove.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you so much for your help and explanation. You helped me out a lot.

Comment: I am glad to help, but you don't answer: $A\cup B \cap C $ you understand as $(A\cup B)\cap C $ or as $A \cup (B \cap C)$ ?

Comment: @zkutch for $A \cup B \cap C$ is equal to $(A \cup B) \cap C $ right? I have to do whatever comes first.

Comment: Let $A'=\{f(x):x\in A\}$ and $B'=\{f(x):x\in B\}$ and $C'=\{f(x):x\in C\}.$ Then $A',B',C'$ can be $any$ sets. Then (i): Is $(A'\cup B)'\cap C'$ always a subset of $(A'\cap B')\cup C'$?  No.  The former is a subset of $C'$ and the latter may nave a member that's in $A'\cap B'$ but not in $C'.$

Comment: Many books write $f(A$) for $\{f(x):x\in A\}.$ This is ok if no member of the domain of $f $is a subset of the domain of $ f$ but set-theorists dislike it as they often have domains with "nesting". Some use $f''A.$ Another, which I like, is $f[A].$

Answer (score 1):

Let me consider $A$ in place of $f(A)$ and hope, that you can translate results to functions.

Accordingly to comments, let me understand $(i)$ as
$$(A \cup B) \cap C \subset (A \cap B) \cup C \quad (i)$$
Classically, in sets, for prove subset by definition we take any element from left side and try to prove, that it is in right. Here I would like suggest following consideration: left side is **subset of** $\boldsymbol{C}$, when right side is $\boldsymbol{C}$ **union** with some extra elements, so left is subset of right.

Accordingly, we write $(ii)$ as
$$(A \cap B) \cup C \subset (A \cup B) \cap C \quad (ii)$$
Here is enough counterexample: lets consider $C=\emptyset$. Then right side, obviously is $\emptyset$, when left side is $A \cap B$. To finish you need consider such functions, for which $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: +1. As I said in a comment to the Q, $f(A),f(B),f(C)$ can be $any$ sets.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWainfleet.